# Sort Multiarray in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I need some help about sorting a multiple array.
 This is what I got:

```
Array ( 
   [ALU0000001] => 
         Array ( [0] => Array ( [period] => 2012 [codCurse] => S12-2030 [idPersona] => ALU0000001 [date] => 2012-04-02 [amount] => 238.00 [active] => X ) 
                 [1] => Array ( [period] => 2012 [codCurse] => S12-2030 [idPersona] => ALU0000001 [date] => 2012-05-02 [amount] => 238.00 [active] => X )
                 [2] => Array ( [period] => 2012 [codCurso] => S12-2030 [idPersona] => ALU0000001 [date] => 2012-06-02 [amount] => 238.00 [active] => X )
                 [3] => Array ( [period] => 2013 [codCurso] => S12-2030 [idPersona] => ALU0000001 [date] => 2013-01-02 [amount] => 238.00 [active] => X )

   [ALU0000005] =>
         Array ( [0] => Array ( [period] => 2013 [codCurse] => S13-2010 [idPersona] => ALU0000005 [date] => 2013-03-01 [amount] => 225.00 [active] => X )
                 [1] => Array ( [period] => 2013 [codCurse] => S13-2010 [idPersona] => ALU0000005 [date] => 2013-03-02 [amount] => 333.00 [active] => X ) 
                 [2] => Array ( [period] => 2013 [codCurse] => S13-2010 [idPersona] => ALU0000005 [date] => 2013-04-02 [amount] => 333.00 [active] => X )
```

I need to sort multiarray by period date to get something like this

```
  Y   M   D
  2012 2012-04-02 ALU00000001 .....
  2012 2012-05-02 ALU00000005 .....
  2012 2012-06-01 ALU00000001 .....
  2013 2013-01-01 ALU00000001 .....
  2013 2013-06-01 ALU00000001 .....
  2013 2013-12-24 ALU00000005 .....
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a custom sort function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the main array keys don't do much (because they're already contained within the values by the `date` key) you can safely ignore them. So first you want to collect all the values into a single array to be able to sort later:

```
$allItems = array();
foreach ($outputArr as $arr) { // $outputArr should be the name of your array
    $allItems = array_merge($allItems,array_values($arr));
}
```

Then you need to sort the array values by the `date` keys:

```
function sortByDate($a,$b) {
    $d1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $d2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $d1 == $d2 ? 0 : ($d1 > $d2 ? 1 : -1);
}
usort($allItems,'sortByDate');
// and there you go.
print_r($allItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

As danp says you will need a custom sort function using [PHP usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

You execute this in Codeigniter using the syntax;

```
usort($data_array, array('controller', 'sort_function'));

function sort_function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```